# d3 does not load tsv data in python flask script

Tags: python, d3.js

New in python and working on a graphing solution. Facing problem with, how d3 loads tsv data.

Got required solution on link - https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 . I downloaded the html file (as index.html) and the data.tsv from the link. With following python script trying to render the index.html.

The issue is not with rendering of html. But how d3 loads tsv data. The html and data.tsv are fine. If the html is loaded from pycharm, it works fine, loads the data and shows the graph.

The html file, templates/index.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, temperature: d[id]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.temperature; }); })
  ]);

  z.domain(cities.map(function(c) { return c.id; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("Temperature, ºF");

  var city = g.selectAll(".city")
    .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.id); });

  city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
});

function type(d, _, columns) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Data file, templates/data.tsv -

```
date    New York    San Francisco   Austin
20111001    63.4    62.7    72.2
20111002    58.0    59.9    67.7
20111003    53.3    59.1    69.4
20111004    55.7    58.8    68.0
20111005    64.2    58.7    72.4
20111006    58.8    57.0    77.0
20111007    57.9    56.7    82.3
20111008    61.8    56.8    78.9
.
.
.
```

Above index.html and data.tsv files are in templates folder . Following is python script to render the index.html (which loads the data.tsv -)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When above script is run on pycharm, the index.html file does not render and I get following error on console -

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2017 23:57:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2017 23:57:53] "GET /data.tsv HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Looks like d3.tsv is not able to load data.tsv . Please help how to render the html properly using above script.

The issue is not with rendering of html. But how d3 loads tsv data. The html and data.tsv are fine. If the html is loaded from pycharm, it works fine, loads the data and shows the graph.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get the data.tsv file by URL (probably something like http://localhost/data.tsv) but your code shows no route for this URL. So you got a 404.

If you want to have the data.tsv file served by your Flask application, and as this file seems static, you should put it in a static directory (not the templates directory) and then include it (many possibilities here, see below) in your template file (say index.html) where your d3 will do the job.

Depending on how works d3 (I don't know what it is), you may want one of the following:

1. To load the file from an URL pointing to your static file in the index.html template
2. To directly include the data in the template itself. To do so, the code under your route must do this job (read the TSV and give it to your template for processing). In that case the TSV file  may not need to be available nor in templates folder, nor in static folder.

**EDIT**

After reading the basic example of d3.js code, I managed to make it work:

1. Make sure you configured your static file path somewhere in you app code

   app = Flask(**name**)
   app.static_url_path='/static'
2. Put you data.tsv file in the **static** file directory
3. In your **index.html** template, modify the path to the TSV file in the javascript part accordingly to the path of your TSV file:

```js
d3.tsv("/static/data/data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, temperature: d[id]};
      })
    };
  });
```

Thats All !

Comment: Actually the data.tsv is loaded by the d3 code in html file. If you keep both files in a directory and open html file from pycharm, the html opens up and presents the chart where values are taken from data.tsv . My concern is to call the html file from python script , where the chart is also populated with values from data.tsv.

Comment: I edited my answer and added the solution to your problem which was a **path** problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was d3 was not able to locate file data.tsv. The key note is data file location should be /static/data/data.tsv .